# How to know when the user is done typing on C# windows form textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-forms-designer

Is there a way to know when the user is done typing on C# windows form textbox?

Rephrase:
Is there a way to know when the user stop typing for few seconds, (maybe 5seconds) on C# windows form textbox?

Comment: Define "done typing". Stops writing, the text-box looses focus, or something else?

Comment: what do you want to do? maybe checking the enter in keydown event, etc.

Comment: ESP but I'm not sure it exists.  ... still waiting for this to know I'm done so I'll hit enter on my own.

Comment: Have you tried reading their mind or just using a 3rd party library that can predict the future? Or maybe some simple heuristic like they haven't typed anything for a few seconds or they moved the focus to another control.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'done typing'?  Of course there is no way to know whether a user is pausing to think before hitting a few more keystrokes.  Is it possible that you are looking to detect when the textbox loses focus?

Comment: Usually when the user reaches 32,767 characters.

Comment: Absolutely, usually it's a button labeled "OK" or "Done" or "Apply" or "Close" or "Exit" or something similar. When they click it, they are done typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the [`OnLostFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onlostfocus.aspx) to tell when the user's focus leaves the textbox.

Otherwise you can use [`OnKeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeypress.aspx) and a timer to tell how long since the last keystroke.

Comment: thank you, Im using the OnKeyPress and a timer to tell how long since the last keystroke. it really works :)

Answer (score 6):

Extend TextBox and create a new event "TextChangedComplete" which is fired off by listening to the TextChanged event and manipulating a Timer. Here is the full code.

```
public class TextBox : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{
    private System.Timers.Timer timer;

    public TextBox()
    {
        this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        this.timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    }

    public TimeSpan TextChangedCompleteDelay
    {
        get { return TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(this.timer.Interval); }
        set { this.timer.Interval = value.TotalMilliseconds; }
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        this.timer.Stop();
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(this.OnTextChangedComplete));
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> TextChangedComplete;

    protected void OnTextChangedComplete()
    {
        if (this.TextChangedComplete != null)
            this.TextChangedComplete(this, new EventArgs());
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs args)
    {
        if (!this.timer.Enabled)
            this.timer.Start();
        else
        {
            this.timer.Stop();
            this.timer.Start();
        }

        base.OnTextChanged(args);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (this.timer != null)
                this.timer.Dispose();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fuzzy area as others have noted.  But the best way I have found to do this is just to have

1. a configurable number of milliseconds specified as your "done" window (how many seconds of inactivity until you consider them done typing)
2. Track **["key up"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx)** events.
3. Have a timer that fires on intervals as long as your inactivity window, and if there has not been a KeyUp event during that time, you can consider the typing complete